# Making calculator in yacc and lex char array

Tags: c, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I'm working with yacc and lex, and i have problem with something.

I working on caluclator. With my calculator you can do this :

**Example:**

```
user: a = 1+3
user: a
calc: 4
```

**Problem** is, i can do it with only one character. But i want with maximum three characters.

**Example:**

```
user: abc = 1+3
user: abc
calc: 4
```

Also i want to add something more.

My code works also with this :

```
user: abc = 1+3
user: abc
calc: 4
user: ab
calc: 4     /* THIS IS BECAUSE IT SCAN ONLY FIRST CHARACTER */
user: a
calc: 4     /* THIS IS BECAUSE IT SCAN ONLY FIRST CHARACTER */
```

Part of my code connecting with my problem :

**-YACC**

```
%{

int symbolVal(char symbol);
void updateSymbolVal(char symbol, int val);

%}

%union {double num; char id;}
%token <id> identifier
%type <id> assignment

%%

assignment : identifier EQUALS exp { updateSymbolVal($1, $3); }

term   : /*something */
       | identifier { $$ = symbolVal($1); }

%%

/* C CODE */

int symbolVal(char symbol) {
    int bucker = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    return symbols[bucket];
}

void updateSymbolVal(char symbol,int val) {
    int bucket = computeSymbolIndex(symbol);
    symbols[bucket] = val;
}

int computeSymbolIndex(char token) {
    int idx = 0;
    idx = token - 'a' + 26;
    return idx;
}
```

I want to say that code **is correct**.

But I want all this but with maximum three characters.

Maybe this can do with array or pointers, but I don't know how.

Comment: You should use strings and arrays but it was too vague to try to help you. Try to do a more functional version and come back when your program stuck

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Thanks a lot for the answer, i know i should use array, but don't know how :/

Comment: In what way this is related to C?

Comment: @Zaibis Read question a litle bit. I maybe need char array in c, function which can take char input like a char array

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in Lex you are returning a single character as a token.
The way to do it is to return a token representing a variable, and the actual name as it's yyval.
Here's some code snippets of what would go into the code to make it work - though I can't help you further without seeing the lex file.

LEX:

```
[a-zA-Z]+   { yylval.s = new std::string(yytext); return tVARIABLE; }
```

YACC:

```
%union {
  str s;    /* symbol name */
}
%token<s> tVARIABLE

...

// on the grammar:
identifier: tVARIABLE { $$ = $1; }
```

Comment: thanks for answer, my lex for this is [a-z]{1,3} { yylval.id = yytext[0]; return identifier; }
I understand what you want to do with code, but, i had to put in string integer value, and i'm doing that with functions in my questions. But when put string, how to take character by character. Do you undrestand me?

Comment: There is really little or no advantage to using `new std::string(yytext)` over the simple `C` `strdup(yytext)` because in both cases you need to manually delete/free the value. But as written, the union declaration should be `%union { std::string* s; }`

Comment: What's wrong with `union { double number; char[4] id; }`? No need to new/delete anything.